# WriteFile taking more time to complete

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel

I am trying to **write data** to the tap adapter(a virtual network interface) through its file descriptor. I opened the file by calling the **"CreateFile"** API and I am able to write the data. I am writing some 100 bytes of data to the file which is sometimes taking more time to complete which I could not figure out what is causing that issue.

I am not getting any error codes and the call is getting success. The only problem is, it is taking more time to complete. I am writing the data 100 times in a loop and only some say 10 iterations **"WriteFile"** calls are taking **more time to complete** which is causing some delay in further processing of the packets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include <ntddndis.h>

#define LINE_LEN 16
#define ETHER_MAX_LEN 65535

#ifdef WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
BOOL LoadNpcapDlls()
{
    _TCHAR npcap_dir[512];
    UINT len;
    len = GetSystemDirectory(npcap_dir, 480);
    if (!len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in GetSystemDirectory: %x", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    _tcscat_s(npcap_dir, 512, _T("\\Npcap"));
    if (SetDllDirectory(npcap_dir) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in SetDllDirectory: %x", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
#endif

void physical_dispatcher_handler(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);

HANDLE hTapAdapter;
pcap_t *port_a;

DWORD WINAPI DataReceiveHandlerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    pcap_loop(port_a, 0, physical_dispatcher_handler, NULL);

    return 0;
}

#define BUFFERSIZE 65535

CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

    //Initilize the critical section
    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);

    printf("\n");
    /*if (argc != 2)
    {
    printf("Usage Error:\tIncorrect number of arguments\n\n");
    _tprintf(TEXT("%s <file_name>\n"), argv[0]);
    return;
    }*/

    hTapAdapter = CreateFile("\\\\.\\Global\\{A2AC038D-EBC1-48F9-B507-BB822AE1C393}.tap",                // name of the write
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
        0,                      // do not share
        NULL,                   // default security
        OPEN_EXISTING,             // create new file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
        NULL);                  // no attr. template

    if (hTapAdapter == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //DisplayError(TEXT("CreateFile"));
        _tprintf(TEXT("Terminal failure: Unable to open file \"%s\" for write.\n"), argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    DWORD threadIdentifier = 0;
    HANDLE threadHandle = CreateThread(
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        DataReceiveHandlerThread,       // thread function name
        NULL,          // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &threadIdentifier);   // returns the thread identifier 


                              // Check the return value for success.
                              // If CreateThread fails, terminate execution. 
                              // This will automatically clean up threads and memory. 

    if (threadHandle == NULL)
    {
        //ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateThread"));
        ExitProcess(3);
    }


    WaitForSingleObject(threadHandle, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(threadHandle);

    return;
}

void physical_dispatcher_handler(u_char *temp1,
    const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
    const u_char *pkt_data)
{
    u_int i = 0;

    /*
    * unused variable
    */
    (VOID*)temp1;

    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    time_t my_time = time(NULL);

    // ctime() used to give the present time 
    printf("Data received in port A - %s", ctime(&my_time));

    // Lock the Critical section
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);

    BOOL bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
        hTapAdapter,           // open file handle
        pkt_data,      // start of data to write
        header->len,  // number of bytes to write
        &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);            // no overlapped structure

    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        //DisplayError(TEXT("WriteFile"));
        printf("Terminal failure: Unable to write to file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (dwBytesWritten != header->len)
        {
            // This is an error because a synchronous write that results in
            // success (WriteFile returns TRUE) should write all data as
            // requested. This would not necessarily be the case for
            // asynchronous writes.
            printf("Error: dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite\n");
        }
        else
        {
            time_t my_time = time(NULL);

            // ctime() used to give the present time 
            printf("Data written to tap - %s", ctime(&my_time));
            _tprintf(TEXT("Wrote %d bytes to successfully.\n"), dwBytesWritten);
        }
    }

    //Release the Critical section
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    return;
}
```

Comment: We do need code in the form of an [mcve] in your question body to help you.

Comment: Govind parmar: Updated the code

Comment: Is it transmission of data over wires or some thing else?

Comment: No.. I am trying to write it to a virtual tap adapter.